# Hokkaido Precipitation in December

Tags: japan, weather-and-climate, hokkaido

How heavy is Hokkaido's snow in Mid-December?

I will be there during that time.

Comment: I'm sure it depends on where you are on the island, and your altitude. Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkaido#Climate?

Comment: 1kg of snow in mid-December = 1 kg of snow in mid-January. ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll very much depend where on the island of Hokkaido you find yourself.

The northern part of the island falls into the '[taiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiga)' zone, with more snow than the rest.  From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkaido#Climate):

> Snowfall varies widely from as much as 11 metres (400 in) on the
>   mountains adjacent to the Sea of Japan down to around 1.8 metres (71
>   in) on the Pacific coast. The island tends to see isolated snowstorms
>   that develop long-lasting snowbanks, in contrast to the constant
>   flurries seen in the Hokuriku region. Total precipitation varies from
>   1,600 millimetres (63 in) on the mountains of the Sea of Japan coast
>   to around 800 millimetres (31 in) (the lowest in Japan) on the Sea of
>   Okhotsk coast and interior lowlands and up to around 1,100 millimetres
>   (43 in) on the Pacific side.

Sapporo, for instance, will [average 132cm (52 inches) of snow during December](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapporo#Climate).